# Shiprocket inventory sync problem on Create Order API

Tags: shiprocket

whenever I am trying to make API call to Shiprocket to create a order, through my web site, it is showing:

[image],

Where do I turn it on? Or is there something else I need to do?

I tried calling create order API of [shiprocket](https://apidocs.shiprocket.in/), this is the API : https://apiv2.shiprocket.in/v1/external/orders/create/adhoc, it should have created a order on my dashboard, instead it's showing a weird error of, inventory sync is off, and I couldn't find a way to turn it on.
Any help?